# Where is help for linux programs located?

Tags: linux

When you pass "--help" as an argument to a program in command line, generally the program provides standard output designed to help the user. Where is the source of this standard output? Is it within its own file or is it embedded within the object code in a series of print statements?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please note that "standard output" does not mean what you think it means.  It is a specific technical term describing the **way** a program prints its data, not the data itself.

Comment: Let me make sure I'm understanding you correctly: when something is printed to the console what appears is standard output but the text that is in the object file itself that is acted upon by instructions isn't itself standard output?

Comment: "Standard Output" refers to the stream that the text the program prints is printed to.  "Standard Output" is usually the console, but it can be redirected into a file, or to a printer, or to the Standard Input of another program, or to /dev/null.  "Standard Error" is another stream that text can be printed to, which is also usually the console, and can be redirected separately.  The text itself is just data which can be sent to standard output or sent to standard error.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually within the program itself -- a series of print statements as you mentioned.